# Boxplot interpretation

Tags: r

I have a data set that has customerID and daily visits. This dataset records the number of times customers visited the site in a day.

```
custID      TotalVisits
 1           6
 2           17
 3           20
 4           25
```

Just to explore the data further, I tried plotting the TotalVists values in a box plot. I am uploading a picture of the plot. The plot doesn't seem to have a lower whisker. q1=1 and there are no values between q1 and  q1-1.5(IQR)..Is this the reason why the boxplot doesn't have the lower whisker? Could you please help me with the interpretation? Is it correct to draw a boxplot without any whiskers?

[image]

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about interpretation of graphics output.

Comment: This happens when the minimum observed value is equal to Q1 (and maybe this is a question to stats.stackexchange.com, not StackOverflow)

Comment: Where should i post this question?

Answer (score 4):

If one quarter or more of you data consist of the same minimum value (looks like 1) , then the minimum and q1 will be that same value and the whisker is on top of the Q1 line.

Comment: Where should i post this question?

Comment: @SS_11 [Cross-Validated](http://stats.stackexchange.com/)